# Where are theme and Compiz settings stored?

Tags: 12.04, settings

Which files in `~/` store settings for Compiz, GTK and icons?

Every new user uses files from `etc\skel`.  I want, when I create a new user, for that user to use my GTK theme, Compiz settings, icons and fonts by default.

Answer (score 1):

OK, solved by reading manuals. .gconf, .config and .locale needed to copy to /etc/skel/

Answer (score 0):

Themes are stored in `.themes` and compiz settings in `.compiz` in your home folder.
Just copy it to the `/etc/skel` folder.

Comment: I don't have .compiz folder. Maybe ~/.compiz folder exist on previous versions of ubuntu? My current - 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Themes and Icons stored in ~/.themes or ~/.icons cannot be shared with other users on the same computer.

To achieve theme and icon sharing you need to store them in **usr/share/themes** and **usr/share/icons** respectively.

**Edited Answer (Based on Comment clarity)**

To copy themes and icons here you need type **gksu nautilus** in Terminal

1: Right click on your Theme folder and select **Properties** (in your case Orta)

2: Select the **Permissions** Tab

3: Go to "Others" and Make sure **Folder access** is set to "Access Files"

4: Change **File Access** to Read or **Read and Write**

Your theme will be available to others

Your ~/.compiz folder is hidden in your Home Folder.  Select **ctrl-h** to reveal.

[image]

Comment: I don't have .compiz folder. I know, that . means hidden file.

Answer (score 0):

The compiz settings are from 11.04 on stored in this folders:

- **Ubuntu-Classic**: `~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1`
- **Unity 2D**: `~/.gconf/apps/compiz`
- **Ubuntu (3D)**: `~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1`

Taken from: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Compiz_CCSM?redirect=no#CCSM-Datenablage
See also this question: [Where are compiz settings saved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99617/where-are-compiz-settings-saved)