# Ubuntu 16.04 - how Lightdm starts Unity

Tags: unity, xorg, compiz, lightdm, xfce

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I have also installed Xfce4 so in Lightdm login screen I can choose Unity or Xfce. I assume that when Lightdm runs Xfce4 desktop environment it uses `/usr/bin/startxfce4` Then Xfce runs a dedicated window manager Xfwm4. A configuration file is stored here:

```
/etc/xdg/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-session.xml
```

Xfce can be used with other window manager, here is a configuration option from that file:

```
<property name="Client0_Command" type="array">
     <value type="string" value="xfwm4"/>
</property>
```

I wonder how Lightdm starts Unity/Compiz ? Unity is a Compiz plugin and can't be used with other window manager, right ? So how exactly Lightdm runs Compiz?

Compiz can be run with parameters, for example:

```
compiz --replace ccp (a configuration plugin which can load other plugins)
```

or

```
compiz --replace composite opengl etc. (a plugin list is defined explicitly)
```

**Update**

`lightdm-session` runs `gnome-session --session=ubuntu`, gnome-session refers to `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/ubuntu.session`. Here is my `ubuntu.session` content:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Ubuntu
RequiredComponents=unity-settings-daemon;
DesktopName=Unity
```

There is nothing about Compiz. So probably `/usr/bin/unity` is run and it load some other config?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: Lightdm uses configration from /usr/share/xsession ubuntu.desktop contains: Exec=gnome-session --session=ubuntu
TryExec=unity but it doesn't explain how Compiz is started

Comment: Please see update

Comment: user specific configurations are in $HOME . See also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz_configuration and http://askubuntu.com/questions/135592/where-are-theme-and-compiz-settings-stored

Comment: It is not configured through lightdm, is is configured in the user settings. See the link I gave you.